# Get request with Authorization Header does not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt, mern

I've developed a system with JWT to authenticate users, **even the authentication process works fine and when I use postman to check the backend it gives me the expected results**. But for some reason when I try to use the same API call from my frontend by using **AXIOS** it does not work.
Before coming to this particular frontend component, I have already saved JWT into my LocalStorage in the browser, so within this component, I use the **useEffect** react hook to call the backend API and try to fetch relevant data. I will put the frontend code below.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const ResearcherProfileScreen = (props) => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let currentToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
    alert(currentToken);
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      try {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${currentToken}`,
          },
        };
        await axios
          .get("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/researcher/profile", config)
          .then((res) => {
            setUserData(res.data.researcher);
            alert("Data Fetch Completed!" + userData.username + " Welcome");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
            props.history.push("/login");
            alert("You are not authorized please login");
          });
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
      }
    };
    fetchUserData();
  }, [props.history]);

  const logOutHandler = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
    alert("TOKEN REMOVED:" + localStorage.getItem("authToken"));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Researcher Profile
      {userData && <button onClick={logOutHandler}>Log Out</button>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ResearcherProfileScreen;
```

When I run this, it **skips then() part and executes the catch() part**, if anyone can explain why it skips then() part it'd be great.

***Note - the exact API call works totally file with PostMan and it fetches the expected result.

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of your browser's network call? i'd like to see the actual problem

Comment: I have found root course for the error, it seems like after fetching data there's a little bit of time gap until the data load into the setState. Since it takes some time, "then" block didn't get execute properly because I wrote some alert pop out command to check whether the data has loaded or not. 
.then((res) => {
            setUserData(res.data.researcher);
            alert("Data Fetch Completed!" + userData.username + " Welcome");
          })

Comment: thank you for the help mate. I really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 0):

After fetching data, **then** block will get execute if there's no errors in the HTTP request.
within then block I have use setState hook **(setUserData)** to store fetched data, and immediately after that line, there's another command to **display alert message** using those previously fetched data.
But it actually **takes some time to store data** by using the setState method, so alert message **can not find the required data** and it raises an error and because of it, the execution skips into the catch block.